# How to show $\operatorname{ann}(M) = \operatorname{ann}(X)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, modules, artinian

If $R$ is left Artinian, $X$ a subset of a left $R$-module $M$, define $\operatorname{ann}(X) = \{a \in R: ax = 0, \forall x\in X \}.$

(a) Show $\operatorname{ann}(M) = \operatorname{ann}(X)$ for some finite subset $X \subset M$

(b) If $\operatorname{ann}(M) = 0$ show $R$ is isomorphic to a submodule of $M$.

So let me tell you what I thought first.

(a) I think that anything that annhilates $m \in M$, certain annhilates $x \in X$. But since there may be more elements annihilating $M$ (because $M$ is the larger set containing $X$), we should get $\operatorname{ann}(X) \subset \operatorname{ann}(M).$ For the other inclusion, we need to construct a left descending series to use the Artinian property.

(b) I am almost certain that this is just done by the multiplication map $R \to M$ given by $r \to rm$, then $R/\ker = R/\operatorname{ann} M = R/0 = M$

> [image]

The above is the answer to part (a), but I just don't quite understand it.

Comment: I've answered part $(b)$ by constructing a counterexample. For part $(a)$, the solution you asked about looks clear to me, so if you could edit your posted question to identify more specifically what points you don't understand, I'll edit my answer to address those points.

Answer (score 1):

The claim of part $(b)$ of the exercise is:

  If
  $R$
  is an artinian ring and
  $M$
  is a finitely generated left
  $R$
  -module such that
  $\text{ann}(M)=0$
  , then
  $M$
  has a submodule isomorphic to
  $R$
  .

However the claim, as stated, is false.

Before presenting a counterexample, we state and prove a lemma.

**lemma:**

  If
  $R$
  is an artinian ring, then no proper left ideal of
  $R$
  is isomorphic, as a left
  $R$
  -module, to
  $R$
  .

**Proof of the lemma:**

Let $R$ be an artinian ring and suppose $A$ is a left ideal of $R$ which is isomorphic, as a left $R$-module, to $R$.

Our goal is to derive a contradiction.

Let $A_0=A$.

Since $A_0$ is isomorphic, as a left $R$-module, to $R$, it follows that $A_0$ has a proper $R$-submodule, $A_1$ say, which is isomorphic, as a left $R$-module, to $R$.

Note that $A_1$ is also a left ideal of $R$.

Iterating the process, we get a strictly descending infinite chain
$$
A_0\supset A_1\supset A_2\supset\cdots 
$$
of left ideals of $R$, contradiction, since $R$ is an artinian ring.

This completes the proof of the lemma.

**The counterexample:**

Let $R=M_n(K)$ where $K$ is a field and $n\ge 2$.

Regarding $R$ as a vector subspace over $K$, $R$ is finite-dimensional (more precisely, it has dimension $n^2$).

Since every left or right ideal of $R$ is closed under multiplication by elements of $K$, it follows that every left or right ideal of $R$ is vector subspace of $R$.

Since the subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space satisfy the descending chain condition, it follows that $R$ is an artinian ring.

For $1\le i\le n$, let $a[i]\in R$ be the $n{\times}n$ matrix with all entries in the $i$-th row equal to $1$ and all other entries equal to $0$.

Let $A$ be the left ideal generated by $a[1]$.

Thus, regarding $A$ as an $R$-module, $A$ is finitely generated.

Note that $\det(a[1])=0$.

If $a\in A$, then $a=ra[1]$ for some $r\in R$, hence $\det(a)=\det(r)\det(a[1])=0$.

Thus all elements of $A$ are singular, so the inclusion $A\subset R$ is proper.

Applying the lemma, no $R$-submodule of $A$ is isomorphic to $R$.

It remains to show $\text{ann}(A)=0$.

Let $r\in\text{ann}(A)$.

For $1\le i,j\le n$, let $e[i,j]\in R$ be the $n{\times}n$ matrix with $(i,j)$-th entry equal to $1$ and all other entries equal to $0$.

By definition of $A$, we have $a[1]\in A$.

For $2\le i\le n$, we have $a[i]=e[i,1]a[1]$.

Thus we have $a_1,...,a_n\in A$.

Then from $rA=0$ we get $ra[i]=0$ for all $i\in\{1,...,n\}$.

From $ra[i]=0$ it follows that the $i$-th column of $r$ is zero.

But then all columns of $r$ are zero, so $r=0$.

Thus we have $\text{ann}(A)=0$, so $A$ qualifies as a counterexample to the claim.